# Is there a way to generate an access token for the Snapchat Marketing API without a browser

Tags: snapchat

The Snapchat Marketing API outlines authentication [in the following steps](https://developers.snapchat.com/api/docs/?shell#full-web-flow-example):

1.) Open the authorize link in the browser:

[https://accounts.snapchat.com/login/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&scope=snapchat-marketing-api&state=wmKkg0TWgppW8PTBZ20sldUmF7hwvU](https://accounts.snapchat.com/login/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=%7Bclient_id%7D&redirect_uri=%7Bredirect_uri%7D&scope=snapchat-marketing-api&state=wmKkg0TWgppW8PTBZ20sldUmF7hwvU)

2.) Authenticated user clicks the authorize button

3.) Physically copy the *code* out of the browser address bar

4.) Issue an API/cURL request- exchanging the authorization code for an access token

5.) When the access token expires- exchange a refresh token (from step 4) for a new one.

---

My main issue with these steps is that the flow is a hybrid web flow/client credentials flow.  I am completely dependent upon a browser session to create an access token.

Furthermore, the code obtained from step 3 needs to be regenerated each time an access token is created with it.

There is no [obvious] way to programmatically create an access token. Is there? Even my Selenium attempts trigger a Captcha ...

Answer (score 4):

Turns out - permanently caching/storing the refresh_token was the ticket.  With it- I can repeat step #5 above ad infinitum.